# Using PROJ6 string with Raster package in R

Tags: raster, r

I know this question has probably been asked many times in different ways, but I have spent a long time looking for a way to add the proper CRS information to rasters (read in with raster::raster()) after the discarded datum error is given. I am using EPSG 6346 currently. For reference, this is my warning:
Warning message:
In showSRID(SRS_string, format = "PROJ", multiline = "NO", prefer_proj = prefer_proj) :
Discarded datum NAD83 (National Spatial Reference System 2011) in Proj4 definition

Is there a way to fix this so that the CRS is complete and uses PROJ6 notation with the raster package? The same CRS seems to work seamlessly in sf package.

I create my rasters in ArcMap/ArcGIS Pro just in case that information is helpful. My R software and packages are up to date